# Arrange Elements In Row At Start And Center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a dilemma that I can't seem to solve. I have an existing row in Flutter. Essentially what I want to accomplish is to have the first element(yellow) at the start of the row, and the second element(red) in the center of the element. I know Row has the `mainAxisAlignment`, but I need a different alignment for each each element (i.e. both `MainAxisAlignment.start` & `MainAxisAlignment.center`). Thanks for any help!

[image: Example Picture]

The closest I have been able to come to this is this:

```dart
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        yellowElement,
        Expanded(child: redElement),
      ],
    );
```

But this is not perfectly centered, it is centered in the available space left over after yellow has taken its space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem few weeks ago and the only solution I found was Stack... like this

```
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 250,
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(width: 50, color: Colors.red),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 20,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Quick question: What is the point of the `Row`. When I replaced the Row widget with a  `Center` widget, the same affect is accomplished?

Comment: Well in this case you can also use centre and get rid of the row

Comment: When would the row be helpful?

Comment: Row is very helpful if you want to line up multiple widgets in one line. Row has a lot of option for alignment and so on.. In your example you are using Stack instead with one widget (red) and positioned  (yellow) so the row is not very helpful here